# CSV in RUBY custom string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 1 field `delivery_time` It is in an array 
include :

```rb
DELIVERY_TIME = [
    I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.order.none_delivery_time"),
    "09:00～12:00",
    "12:00～14:00",
    "14:00～16:00",
    "16:00～18:00",
    "18:00～20:00",
    "19:00～21:00",
    "20:00～21:00",
  ].freeze
```

when I downloaded the csv directory it was in the form

`"09:00～12:00"`

but i want now when I download it will take the form :

```rb
"0912"
```

how to customize it?

my code:

```
def perform
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      orders.each do |order|
        csv << create_row(order)
    end
  end
end


def create_row(order)
    row << order.delivery_time
end
```

Comment: is delivery_time enum? or it's value must be one of the DELIVERY_TIME? don't understand why it's an array?

Comment: It is intended to display selections in the view, allowing the user to enter only these values

Answer (score 2):

AFAIU, you need to modify `DELIVERY_TIME` to fit your format. `CSV` is absolutely out of scope here. So to transform values, one should split by `～` and take the hour from the result.

```rb
DELIVERY_TIME = [
    "09:00～12:00",
    "12:00～14:00",
    "14:00～16:00",
    "16:00～18:00",
    "18:00～20:00",
    "19:00～21:00",
    "20:00～21:00",
].freeze

DELIVERY_TIME.map { |s| s.split('～').map { |s| s[0...2] }.join }
#⇒ ["0912", "1214", "1416", "1618", "1820", "1921", "2021"]
```

A safer method would be to use `DateTime#parse` for this

```rb
require 'time'
DELIVERY_TIME.map do |s|
  s.split('～').map { |s| DateTime.parse(s).strftime("%H") }.join
end
#⇒ ["0912", "1214", "1416", "1618", "1820", "1921", "2021"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not real clear what you're asking, but I'd probably start with something like this:

```
"09:00～12:00".scan(/\d{2}/).values_at(0, 2).join # => "0912"
```

Using that in some code:

```
"09:00～12:00".scan(/\d{2}/).values_at(0, 2).join # => "0912"

DELIVERY_TIME = [
    'blah',
    "09:00～12:00",
    "12:00～14:00",
    "14:00～16:00",
    "16:00～18:00",
    "18:00～20:00",
    "19:00～21:00",
    "20:00～21:00",
  ].freeze

ary = [] << DELIVERY_TIME.first
ary += DELIVERY_TIME[1..-1].map { |i|
  i.scan(/\d{2}/).values_at(0, 2).join
}  
# => ["blah", "0912", "1214", "1416", "1618", "1820", "1921", "2021"]
```